# WPF Richtextbox XamlWriter behaviour

Tags: wpf, xaml, richtextbox, xamlreader

I am trying to save some c# source code into the database. Basically I have a RichTextBox that users can type their code and save that to the database.

When I copy and paste from the visual studio environment, I would like to preserve the formating etc. So I have chosen to save the FlowDocuments Xaml to the database and set this back to the RichTextBox.Document.

My below two function serialise and deserialise the RTB's contents.

```
     private string GetXaml(FlowDocument document)
    {
        if (document == null) return String.Empty;
        else{
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb);
            XamlDesignerSerializationManager sm = new XamlDesignerSerializationManager(xw);
            sm.XamlWriterMode = XamlWriterMode.Expression;                

            XamlWriter.Save(document, sm );
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    private FlowDocument GetFlowDocument(string xamlText)
    {
        var flowDocument = new FlowDocument();
        if (xamlText != null) flowDocument = (FlowDocument)XamlReader.Parse(xamlText);
        // Set return value
        return flowDocument;
    }
```

However when I try to serialise and deserialise the following code, I am noticing this incorrect(?) behaviour

```
using System;
public class TestCSScript : MarshalByRefObject
{

}
```

Serialised XAML is

`using
                    System;
                
                
                    
                
                
                    public
                     
                    class TestCSScript :
                    MarshalByRefObject
                
                {}{
                
                    
                
                
                    }`

Notice the the new set of "{}"

What am I doing wrong here... Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Looks like a bug to me -- I've reported it at Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/WPF/feedback/details/563677/wpf-paragraphs-with-a-leading-curly-bracket-do-not-xamlwriter-save-correctly

Comment: thanks - glad to know that I am not alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resigned to a tardy solution for now, but if any of you finds a clean one, please post it.

I have used a Replace call of Stringbuilder to remove the undesired characters.

```
    private string GetXaml(FlowDocument document)
    {
        if (document == null) return String.Empty;
        else
        {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
            {
                XamlDesignerSerializationManager sm = new XamlDesignerSerializationManager(xw);
                sm.XamlWriterMode = XamlWriterMode.Expression;

                XamlWriter.Save(document, sm);
            }
            sb.Replace("{}", "");
            return sb.ToString();
        }

    }
```

I have a feeling that when the xamlwriter encounters "{" character - it intreprets that as a binding expression. I wonder what the escape sequence is for this character.

Note - I tried changing the

```
XamlWriterMode from XamlWriterMode.Expression to XamlWriterMode.Value
```

with no joy.

Comment: {} is a [XAML escape sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744986.aspx) so what you are seeing is perfectly valid. The real question is: why does this bother you? Your intention is to (de)serialize a FlowDocument into/from XAML which is obviously working for you. So why make a fuss about {}? You should not try to interpret serialized content.

Comment: the content I am trying to serialise is C# code. when I reload the serialised content back to the richtext box, the new set of {} would make my code un-compilable. The next iterations of any serialisations would add a new set of {} for each { encountered. Please note that <b>(FlowDocument)XamlReader.Parse(xamlText); </b> is not removing these characters. I understand that serialised bit, but when deserialising - should the reader not remove the escape sequence